# Updating multiple rows Linq vs SQL

Tags: .net, sql, linq

Some time ago I wrote a piece of code to update multiple rows in a database table. The code was like this

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
db.Execute("UPDATE Details SET IsActive = 0 WHERE MasterId = 1");
```

Then the other day when I got the latest version of the file I saw that somebody changed the code to something like this

```
var details = from d in db.details where d.MasterId == 1 select d;
foreach (var detail in details)
  detail.IsActive = false;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

So my question is: What is the better way to update multiple rows? Using Linq or SQL?

Answer (score 14):

Check the approach used in this article:

- [Batch Updates and Deletes with LINQ to SQL](https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: Here is the working link: https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/

Answer (score 9):

I'd say it depends on whether efficiency or abstraction from the database is more important to you.  The SQL way is going to create a dependency in your code that is harder to track, but is more efficient.  The LINQ sample quoted removes the dependency on hand-coded SQL but involves at least 2 queries and some server side processing.

Comment: I won't add an extra answer - my thought is that if you wanted an answer then it would have to be SQL for a *set* operation i.e. where you want to affect a lot of rows with a single statement but as you say its actually a tradeoff, what compromise do you want to make.

Answer (score 4):

PLINQO has implemented the batch updates and deletes and each entity generated by plinqo can use the batch update and delete operations.

```
context.Task.Update(t => t.Id == 1, t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});
```

This will perform an `Update Task Set StatusId = 2 Where Id = 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < pListOrderDetail.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < stempdata.Count; j++)
    {
        pListOrderDetail[i].OrderID = pOrderID;
        pListOrderDetail[i].ProductID = stempdata[j].pProductID;
        pListOrderDetail[i].Quantity = stempdata[j].pQuantity;
        pListOrderDetail[i].UnitPrice = stempdata[j].pUnitPrice;
        pListOrderDetail[i].Discount = stempdata[j].pDiscount;
        db.SubmitChanges();
        break;
    }
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Linq-to-SQL version is going to `SELECT` every row from the `details` table that matches the query, pull them into memory, and create objects for them. Then when it applies the updates, it will use a separate `UPDATE` statement for each object, and will (by default) include a `WHERE` clause that checks the value of every column to make sure it hasn't changed since you did the `SELECT`. If the row has changed, Linq will throw an exception.

The Linq version of the code is going to be **MUCH** slower (think 100x or 1000x slower), and expose you to additional exceptions.

The SQL version might be a bit harder to maintain as you refactor code in the future, but it will make a world of difference to your database.

I generally feel that Linq-to-SQL is great for selects and individual updates, and maybe for small batches the database would be fast enough that the extra queries wouldn't a problem, but I would have to think carefully before I used Linq for large batches, or on a web server.