# Update elements of sequence with linq without iterating on sequence using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have a query like below and i want to update all elements of sequence. but without using foreach/for

```
var res = _context.tbl1.Where(/* Conditions here */);
res.//Using a method to performing changes;
```

Comment: And how do you think that will work, if you dont go through every element?

Comment: hm... i think should be exist an Extension Method to do this, otherwise why we can iterate each element using Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can do set based updates in linq-to-sql as you can in sql, i'm afraid you can't.  You either have to individually update each l2s object and call `SubmitChanges()` when you're done, or call `ExecuteCommand()` with your sql query.

Here's a thread you might be interested in - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/0f014318-5259-43c7-8518-06948cec465e

**Edit:** Actually, this may be of interest to you - 
[Updating multiple rows Linq vs SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348417/updating-multiple-rows-linq-vs-sql)

If you have a look there's a link to here - http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx which looks kinda cool.  Might have to check it out myself!

Comment: thanks, so i can't do that and also thanks for provided links. I got the answer

Answer (score 2):

Write an extension method for it

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in seq)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But note that under the hood you're still looping through - just like the Where extension method and all the others. The extension methods hide the looping.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` that did iterate and perform the action you required, potentially using a delegate or Func to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `Select`?

Comment: In that case, see Frank's answer. LINQ by default can only be used to *select* data, not update it.